# One to many to many for tree level view from resultSet

Tags: dictionary, collections, treeview, openstreetmap, resultset

I am having a result set as shown below (Pasted the Database result into excel for easy interpretation).

[image]

This data needs to be shown in the UI as a tree level as shown in the below image.

[image]

So, now if the user clicks the ***First Row*** -> it will expands to the ***Data One*** and ***Data Two***. Again, if the user clicks on the ***Data One***, it will show the ***DataA, DataB, DataC***. For this we have a pojo class with links. I just need to collect the data  from the resultset. How to do that logic? Please help.

Comment: What programming language / framework / library are you talking about?

Comment: Its in Java.. plain Java only...

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to work with SWT, you can try nebula project:

**NatTable**: https://www.eclipse.org/nattable/

**XViewer**: https://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/xviewer/xviewer.php